# Bounding ratio of nearby poins

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Silly arithmetic question that I'm not able to resolve: Suppose $a, b, a', b'$ are positive reals with $|a-a'|\le\varepsilon$, $|b-b'|\le\varepsilon$ and $a\ge\tau b$. I want a lower bound on $a'/b'$ in terms of $\varepsilon$ and $\tau$. It seems like such a bound should be possible, given that $a$ is not far from $a'$, $b$ is not far from $b'$, and I know a bound on $a/b$. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $\tau,\epsilon$. For arbitrary $a,b,a',b'$ the lower bound is $0$: Take $a=\tau b,b=\epsilon/\tau,a'=a-\epsilon,b'=b+\epsilon$, $a'/b'=(\tau b-\epsilon)/(b+\epsilon)=0.$ (This is assuming $a>\epsilon$, otherwise just take $a'=0$.